# Детекция области диска зрительного нерва

Tags: c++, алгоритм, opencv

На входе имеется изображение

[image: исходное изображение]

... которое посредством оператора Собеля преобразую к такому виду

[image: оператор Собеля]

Жёлтым овалом я выделил интересующую область для детекции, то есть то, что необходимо обнаружить. Как хорошо видно, кровеносные сосуды отчётливо выделяются и, словно дороги, ведущие в Рим, соединяются в одной области. Вот, собственно, этот "Рим" и требуется найти. Я пробовал построить вертикальную и горизонтальную гистограмму градиента с тем, чтобы по пикам на графике найти максимумы по вертикали и горизонтали, однако слишком большое количество "вен" в разных частях изображения фактически сводят на нет профит от данного подхода. Каким ещё способом было бы возможно обнаружить область схождения кровеносных сосудов?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, думаю вам нужен какой-то из алгоритмов [определения особенностей изображения.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision))  [Возможно этот сможет помочь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection) еще до применения оператора Собеля.

Comment: @igumnov Не могли бы Вы раскрыть свою идею как-нибудь более развёрнуто, поскольку я не могу сообразить, каким образом альтернативное выделение линий на изображении сможет помочь решить задачу? Спасибо.

Comment: [Вот эту статью гляньте.](ftp://ftp.nada.kth.se/CVAP/reports/cvap191.pdf) 23-24 страницу. Там автор находит ладонь на картинке с рукой у которой пальцы раздвинуты,  очень похоже на то что вас происходит.

Comment: Хотя я похоже поторопился и это немного не то, там просто замена оператора Собеля, все равно после получения линий придется как-то искать участок где их больше всего пересекается.

Comment: **UPD:** скорее всего для поиска пересечений дальше нужно прогонать это через какой-нибудь corner detector. Там их несколько. [Первый](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) и [второй](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/good_features_to_track/good_features_to_track.html).

Comment: @igumnov Нет, не поторопились. Там дальше на картинках пальцы руки приводятся к единому целому, как бы до одной толстой линии. Тогда с моей задачей, обнаруженные толстые линии "вен" можно утончить и провести скелетонизацию. Ну и как бы попробовать поискать тогда точку пересечения. Наверное так.

Comment: @igumnov С углами - не знаю. С одной стороны их много по всему изображению будет, с другой - почему бы не брать только те, где Собель показывает наибольший уровень градиента... Вполне может быть.

Comment: Короче мой окончательный вариант ridge detection из статьи потом к полученному corner detection с вашей поправкой на Собеля и дальше просто разбиение картинки на квадраты и подсчет в каком из них оказалось больше кружков, которые показал исправленный Собелем corner detection. Надеюсь это вам как-то поможет. Поздно уже, пойду спать. Счастливо.

Comment: Ого, интересные у вас задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы попробовал следующий подход:

1. Разбить все изображение на сетку из квадратов. Размер квадрата будет определять точность локализации области зрительного нерва, в то же время, размер стороны квадрата должен быть больше ширины сосуда. Размер стороны в 2 раза меньше, чем диаметр области для детекции на изображении мне кажется разумным.
2. Для каждого квадрата сетки узнал бы, с какими квадратами он соединен сосудами. Таким образом получил бы граф кровеносных сосудов.
3. Выделил бы из графа наибольший связный подграф.
4. Нашел бы *центр* наибольшего подграфа. Если сосуды расходятся приблизительно равномерно от области нахождения зрительного нерва, то данный центр должен совпадать с положением зрительного нерва.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть попробовать "запустить потоки" по сосудам от периферии к центру?
(что-то напоминающее трассировку печатных плат (или кристаллов))

Во внешнем цикле делаем по одному шагу для всех потоков. Если очередной шаг потока не приближается к центру ни по X, ни по Y (это важно, не расстояние от центра увеличивается, а обе координаты), поток прекращается. Также поток прекращается, если он достигает точки, которую уже посетил другой поток.

В этом случае анализируем направление потоков и если оно встречное, то запоминаем такую точку.

Мне кажется, что область в которой локализуется максимальное количество таких точек будет совпадать с искомой.